# ASPNETDB.MDF file not showing up in APP_DATA

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm taking Microsoft's walk through on MVC 2 Forms Authentication - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff398049.aspx

According to the walk through, when I register a user, ASP.NET creates the ASPNETDB.MDF file and it is supposed to show up in my APP_DATA folder upon refreshing in the solution explorer. The problem is, for me it is not and I want to have a look inside so I can understand it's structure.

I can continue to run the project and login as the user I created, yet the ASPNETDB.MDF file is still not visible under the APP_DATA folder.

Am I missing something here? Any help is appreciated as always!

Cheers

Chris

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try clicking the "Show All Files" button in the Solution Explorer in Visual Studio.  I believe the file gets generated, but it's not included in the Web Application project automatically.

Comment: This showed up the files but didn't work for me. Visual Studio 2010 says I have to *downgrade* my current SQL Server to SQL Server 2008 Express. But I *am* running SQL Server 2008 Express!

Comment: @Xenan : any luck on the above problem? I'm facing the same issue with VS 2013 Express