# Where is the database my program created?

Tags: c#, .net, database, configuration, sql-server-express

I have an ASP .NET MVC application. "MovieDBContext" is a method of a controller that returns some basic information about a list of movies in a view. I know the database is working as I can enter new movies and delete them etc. using Code First and Entity Framework.

This is the web.config file connection settings:

```
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MovieDBContext"
        connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;database=MvcMovie;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="ApplicationServices"
         connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

I've looked in my list of databases in SQL Server Management Studio but it's not there. I've clicked on the App_Data file in the Visual Studio 2010 but that doesn't open up any databases. I've wanted a way to look at the data in the database other than through the program itself, preferably the management studio. Any ideas?

Comment: When you log into Sql Server Management Studio, type .\SQLEXPRESS as the server name, you should see it there?

Comment: Visual Studio 2010 may be hiding it, try clicking "Show all files", or browse to the directory in windows explorer.

Comment: AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf

Comment: Stop using the User Instance / AttachDbFileName settings.

Comment: @Greg Smith Thanks for the tip but that didn't work

Comment: @ChrisPebble this worked thanks! it now shows the database, thanks!

Comment: @AaronBertrand this worked thanks! it created a new database but that's how it should have been at the start. I can also view this one through the management studio

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASPNETDB.MDF file not showing up in APP\_DATA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4435218/aspnetdb-mdf-file-not-showing-up-in-app-data)

Comment: @ChrisPebble How would I view the database in the management studio?

Comment: @ChrisPebble This question has some new suggestions though, but yeah it is a duplicate :/ My wording was probably bad when I did a check search

Answer (score 0):

The database files will be created in the `App_Data` folder. This will happen once you start writing something to it, not when the application is run. For example if you register a new user the database file will be created.

Comment: It wasn't appearing there at first, but now I realise I had to click the "Show all files" option.