# Location of DB file in Visual Studio 2012 MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I have been trying to learn ASP.NET MVC, and [have been following this tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application/).

It is working fine. However, it is mentioned in the tutorial that if I include "`AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\ContosoUniversity1.mdf`"

In the connection string, my database file will show up inside App_Data Folder.

However, I cannot find the database file. It is created, however does not show up inside the folder.

Where is it located (in general) ?

Comment: Take a look at this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4435218/aspnetdb-mdf-file-not-showing-up-in-app-data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try clicking the "Show All Files" button in the Solution Explorer in Visual Studio. I believe the file gets generated, but it's not included in the Web Application project automatically.
or right click on the App_Data Folder and then click on open in file explorer you will find file there but mostly the file is hidden.